# How can I navigate to /tmp?

Tags: nautilus

I want to find the downloaded videos on my hardisk.

Comment: This is fun to read, but I understand that now Ubuntu does a good job of hiding this from the user. It's always good to ask.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First launch the file manager by clicking on "Places" in the top menu and selecting "Home Folder". From there click on "File System" on the left part and that will take you to the / directory, from there you'll see `/tmp`, which you can then browse to.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Type **nautilus /tmp** in terminal it will open /tmp

Or Goto My Computer--->File System

All the system files and folders including **tmp** will be located there.

Comment: You could add a screen shot of how to get to the location.

Comment: Or hit ALT-F2 on your desktop and type /tmp in there (you don't need to type "nautilus" when you use ALT-F2).

Answer (score 6):

/tmp is located under the root file system (/). If you want to access it using Nautilus windoe manager (GUI) use the above suggestion. if you want to access it via Command Line Interface (CLI), just open a terminal (depending to your user interface: GNOME or KDE) and type cd /tmp. You should be there in a jiffy :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying to access the files downloaded by flash, they have been moved to the browser cache instead of the /tmp folder.

For Chromium this means:

```
~/.cache/chromium/Cache/
```

For Chrome:

```
~/.cache/google-chrome/Cache/
```

For Firefox:

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<some-random-string>.default/Cache/
```