# I have no idea what to do! (dpkg: warning)

Tags: dpkg

I'm sorry, I didn't want to show pages of the same msg.

It's kubuntu 20.04

If there's any info I can provide I will do, but I don't just want to throw a whole load of stuff.

This is the last bit....

```
Setting up samba-common (2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6) ...
dpkg: error processing package samba-common (--configure):
 installed samba-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up nfs-common (1:1.3.4-2.5ubuntu3.3) ...
dpkg: error processing package nfs-common (--configure):
 installed nfs-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.04-1ubuntu26.7) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64 (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin depends on samba-common (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6); however:
  Package samba-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on samba-common (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6); however:
  Package samba-common is not configured yet.
 samba depends on samba-common-bin (= 2:4.11.6+dfsg-0ubuntu1.6); however:
  Package samba-common-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-is-python2 (2.7.17-4) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Setting up autofs (5.1.6-2ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package autofs (--configure):
 installed autofs package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi:
 grub-efi depends on grub-efi-amd64 (= 2.04-1ubuntu26.7); however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
  Package grub-pc is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-common
 nfs-common
 grub-efi-amd64
 samba-common-bin
 samba
 autofs
 grub-efi
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: what ubuntu version? when do you get these warnings? please post the whole terminal out put

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg warning files list file for package missing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949760/dpkg-warning-files-list-file-for-package-missing)

Answer (score 2):

There's some information that we're lacking, but I'll work with this.
It looks like you're just missing a file from being installed, specifically 'python3-simplejson'.

Try this real quick and restart your computer for everything to possibly need to take effect.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-simplejson
```

If you're still having issues or if it's asking you for dependent packages try installing (or reinstalling) the usual dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libc6 python
```

Comment: OK folks, thanks for your help. Sorry I didn't get back in touch but my system went offline. I ended up just wiping the disk and starting again so we'll never know what it was now, til the next time!